# Could not cast value of type __NSCFString to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get 'fname' from my Json , this is my code:

```
let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse!)
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let Results = (json as! NSDictionary)
                    if (Results.value(forKey: "error") == nil) {
                        print(Results)
                            let x = Results.value(forKey: "user") as! NSDictionary
                            let fname= x.value(forKey: "fname")
                            print(fname!)
                      //  self.userpass = ["username": self.usernametf.text!,"pass":self.passwordtf.text!]
                       // UserDefaults.standard.set(self.userpass, forKey: "userpass1")
                    }else{
                        print("wrong pass")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
            }
```

and this is my Json:

```
{
status = 1;
user = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"fname\":\"\\u0645\\u0633\\u0639\\u0648\\u062f\",\"lname\":\"\\u0627\\u0645\\u0627\\u0645\\u06cc\\u0627\\u0646\",\"email\":\"smemamian@yahoo.com\",\"phone\":\"093666023695\",\"pass\":\"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b\",\"bd\":\"1991-12-20\",\"byear\":\"1991\",\"bmonth\":\"12\",\"bday\":\"20\",\"img\":\"1480141509_1.png\",\"isdelete\":\"1\",\"current_date\":\"2016-11-09 10:04:36\"}";}
```

but I'm getting error `"Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1012ec4a0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1012ed288)."`

Comment: It's because it's JSON within JSON. `let x = Results.value(forKey: "user") as! String`, then convert `x` into `(NS)Data`, let's called it `xData`, call again `let xJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: xData!, options: .mutableContainers)`

Comment: The value for key `user` is doubtless a(nother) JSON **string**. You need to deserialize it, too. And **do not** use `NSDictionary`and `.mutableContainers` in Swift nor `valueForKey` at all.

Comment: @M_STRM74 Its like (user=" ") surrounded with (" ") i guess it is taking it as a string value instead of NSDictionary.

Comment: @Larme You really saved my life!